# Recover denormalized data during training

Tags: keras, normalization, denormalization

I'm using TensorFlow/Keras to train a CNN. I've normalized BOTH my inputs (X) and outputs (Y) data (I got 2 inputs and 3 outputs in my problem) using MinMaxScaler between 0 and 1, like:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler # For normalizing data
scaler = MinMaxScaler() # Define limits for normalize data
X = scaler.fit_transform(X) # Normalize input data
Y = scaler.fit_transform(Y) # Normalize output data
```

The thing is, during training, at each epoch, i'm getting a normalized value of loss. Is there anyway i can get the original loss values instead?

I know there is the following inverse transform:

```
X = scaler.inverse_transform(X) # Inverse transformation of input data
Y = scaler.inverse_transform(Y) # Inverse transformation of output data
```

But i'm not sure how to perform this denormalization inside the model.

Comment: Why do you want the "original" loss values? It should be possible with custom loss functions and/or lambda layers, but I feel like that's not worth the impact on your code.

Comment: It's a regression problem, and with the denormalized data would be easier to interpretate the results i'm getting at the end of each epoch.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb, you shouldn't try to change loss functions in an attempt to make them more interpretable. For your situation, I would recommend making a [custom metric](https://keras.io/metrics/#custom-metrics). Within the custom metric function that you create, you can do the inverse transform on y_true and y_pred, and then calculate whatever you want to on them (e.g. MAE).

If you want to do something that cannot merely be handled as a metric, you can always create a [custom lambda callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/#lambdacallback) that is run `on_epoch_end` (or whenever else you want).

Comment: I see... so, i can create a custom metric and use that as a loss function instead of my regular loss (i'm using MSE at the moment)?

Comment: @MuriloSouza **Don't try to change your loss function.** If you needed to, you could create a custom loss function. However, you're looking for "interpretable" numbers, so you should not touch your losses and instead use a custom metric. I suggested MAE because I'd say it's more interpretable than MSE, but it's your choice, depending on what you want to see.